# Expire dates on coconut milk

Tags: coconut, coconut-milk

I just bought a case of coconut milk in cartons and the expire date says 12MR01. Does this mean it expired 4 years ago?

Comment: Not necessarily. It could even be 15 years ago. If it's powdered ("carton" means different things to different people), and the inner bag is sealed, I'd use it anyway (after inspecting). I have coconut milk powder bought short dated years ago and kept sealed until recently. I don't have as much experience with liquid coconut milk, only in tins.

Comment: Hello and welcome! Unless stated that it is an expiration date, it could also be a date of manufacture or packing. The best way to find out is to contact the company and ask.